# Express GET error Requested URL not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just added a feature where admin can upload product images. I am using **multer** for that.
But, when I opened that product, image was not showing & I am getting an error:

`Requested URL: /uploads/image-1625831584164.png not found!`
[image]

Images are getting uploaded to the folder:

[image]

Then why I am getting this error?
my source code:

**productController.js**

```
//  @description: Update a Product
//  @route: PUT /api/product/:id
//  @access: Private/Admin
exports.updateProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { name, price, description, image, brand, category, countInStock } =
      req.body;
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

    if (product) {
      product.name = name;
      product.price = price;
      product.description = description;
      product.image = image;
      product.brand = brand;
      product.category = category;
      product.countInStock = countInStock;

      const updatedProduct = await product.save();
      res.json(updatedProduct);
    } else {
      const error = new Error("Product not Found!");
      error.status = 404;
      next(error);
    }

    const createdProduct = await product.save();
    res.status(201).json(product);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

here is my upload code using multer.

**uploadRoutes**

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "../uploads");
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    );
  },
});

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  const filetypes = /jpg|jpeg|png/;
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (extname && mimetype) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb("Images only!");
  }
}

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
});

router.post("/", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  res.send(`/${req.file.path}`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: "C:/Users/dogra/Documents/Web Development/Portfolio/FullStack/market/.env",
});
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
connectDB();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// IMAGES FOLDER
app.use(express.static("./uploads"));

// Routes
const productRoutes = require("./routes/productRoutes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const orderRoutes = require("./routes/orderRoutes");
const uploadRoutes = require("./routes/uploadRoutes");

app.use("/api", productRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/orders", orderRoutes);
app.use("/api/upload", uploadRoutes);

app.get("/api/config/paypal", (req, res) =>
  res.send(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID)
);

// uploads to "/uploads" folder
app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/uploads")));

// Check's If the route is not defined and passes 404 error
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error(`Requested URL: ${req.path} not found!`);
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});

// Error handler
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      success: false,
      status: error.status || 500,
      message: error.message,
    },
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} on port ${PORT}`)
);
```

Comment: how are you serving files in the uploads folder? express.static?

Comment: additionally your saving product and responding twice

Comment: To serve static assets you need to set express static middle ware in your app.js file. app.use("/uploads", express.static("./uploads"));

Comment: @AnkushDogra how did you declare admin? for example, there is a register page for normal users. how do we register an admin in nodejs

Comment: hi @Sarah you can create a boolean value `isAdmin` for every user, and for the users you want to be admin set that `isAdmin` to `true`.  Then you can add a middleware to check if isAdmin is true for the user or not. If you are intrested you can check the [repo](https://github.com/ankushdogradev/Market) here (Although not Completed) :

Comment: @AnkushDogra i know. but the client can't go to databases and change the admin check. how can we make it easier to declare an admin. in python we use the command `create super user` to declare an admin. is there anthing like that in nodejs?
thanks for the repo

Comment: @sarah correct me if  I am wrong but you are saying If a **client can go to database and check itself admin** doesn't that makes your website vulnerable. Like, a normal user can edit or completely delete your websites data.  I don't know about python but there are many good tutorials on youtube about that like : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jI4K7L-LI58

Comment: @AnkushDogra thanks. i will check it.
Secondly, there should be an easy way for an admin to make someone else admin. thats all i was trying to say

Comment: @sarah for that purpose you can create a specific route for admin's from where you can edit user data like toggling `isAdmin` value `true`/`false` like I did. you can check my repo mentioned in above link. I have updated the project images there you can see how easy it is for an admin, to make existing user admin, just by checking a box.